# Text appearing on an image when hover, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am creating a website for a coding course I am doing at my Uni and one of the requirements is to use JavaScript. I have added it in so that when you hover over the images on the website, the text will appear on the image. However, I want to make the text white and I want it to be centered, I have tried everything but the text won't budge from the top left-hand corner of each image. Any tips?

```js
      $('.image-container').on('mouseenter', function(){
       $(this).children('div').show();
      });

      $('.image-container').on(
        'mouseleave',
        function(){
          $(this).children('div').hide();
        }
      );
```

```css
      div#image-wrap {
       background-color: white;
       padding: 0;
       margin: auto;
       text-align: center;
      }
      div.image-column {
       width: 31.5%;
       background-color: white;
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0px;
      }
      .image-container img {
        width: 100%;
        transition: .5s ease;
      }
      .image-container:hover img {
        opacity: .6;
        transition: .5s ease;
      }
      #img-name {
       position: absolute;
       display: none;
       transition: .5s ease;
      }
      #img-name:hover {
       opacity: 1;
       transition: .5s ease;
      }
      p {
       margin: 0px;
       font-size: 20px;
       text-align: justify;
       font-size: 1.5vw;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-wrap">
       <div class="image-column" id="col-1">
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Pier To Pier, Brighton Pier</p>
         </div>
         <img src="images/piertopier.jpg.JPG">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Looking Back, Brighton Beach</p>
         </div>
         <img src="images/lookingback.jpg.JPG">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Heart Shaped Flocks, Brighton Pier</p>
         </div>
         <img src="images/heartshapedflocks.jpg.JPG">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make the text in the center you need the text's container to stretch and have the same width as the image, you can do that by making the `position` of the parent `relative` and the text's container `absolute` with `left:0` and `right:0`, and to center the text use `text-align:center` and to make it white, wel .. `color:#fff`,

to center it vertically, use `display:flex` on the container and `self-align:center` on the text

( i added background red just to show the text, remove it when you put your images in place )

```css
div#image-wrap {
       background-color: white;
       padding: 0;
       margin: auto;
       text-align: center;
       
      }
      div.image-column {
       width: 31.5%;
       background-color: white;
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0px;
      }
      .image-container{
          position: relative;
          display: flex;
          margin-top: 10px;
          text-align:center;
      }
      .image-container img {
        width: 100%;
        transition: .5s ease;
      }
      .image-container:hover img {
        opacity: .6;
        transition: .5s ease;
      }
      #img-name {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;  /* stretch the text container */
       right: 0; /* stretch the text container */
       
       transition: .5s ease;
       display: flex;
       align-self: center;
       text-align: center;
      }
      #img-name:hover {
       opacity: 1;
       transition: .5s ease;
      }
      p {
       margin: 0px;
       font-size: 20px;
       text-align: center; /* to make the text in the center */
       color: #fff; /* to make the text white */
       font-size: 1.5vw;
       width: 100%;
       text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
       z-index: 999;
     }
```

```html
<div id="image-wrap">
       <div class="image-column" id="col-1">
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Pier To Pier, Brighton Pier</p>
         </div>
         <img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100/dog">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Looking Back, Brighton Beach</p>
         </div>
         <img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Heart Shaped Flocks, Brighton Pier</p>
         </div>
         <img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100/flower">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank You! Okay so the text is centered at the top of the image, but it still does not appear at the center of the image?

Comment: you want it centered vertically ? ijust edited my answer for that

Comment: Um I'm not sure, at the moment i have my image and the text is centred but is positioned at the very top of the image and doesnt sit directly in the centre of the image which I would like

Comment: Thank you! You've been so much help, the only other thing is, when I hover it blurs out the image and makes it more opaque, but when I set the text to be white is doesn't appear presumably because it is the same colour as the more opaque whitened image. Is there anyway to get around this? Because I'd really like the text to be white!!

Comment: well .. you can add `text-shadow` and `z-index:999` to the `p` , ( updated snippet )

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been so helpful, I really appreciate it!! Have a good rest of your day!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  p {
   margin: 0px;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center !important;
   font-size: 1.5vw;
   color: white !important;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set position relative to image-container class. Add top:50%, left:0, right:0 for #img-name. And the last one remove text-align: justify from p. 
You can easily add color white but if you add color to white it will not visible.

```js
      $('.image-container').on('mouseenter', function(){
       $(this).children('div').show();
      });

      $('.image-container').on(
        'mouseleave',
        function(){
          $(this).children('div').hide();
        }
      );
```

```css
  div#image-wrap {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  div.image-column {
    width: 31.5%;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .image-container{
   position:relative;
  }
  .image-container img {
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }

  .image-container:hover img {
    opacity: .6;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }

  #img-name {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    transition: .5s ease;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0
  }
  #img-name:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }

  p {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
   
    font-size: 1.5vw;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-wrap">
       <div class="image-column" id="col-1">
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Pier To Pier, Brighton Pier</p>
         </div>
         <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2GGn.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Looking Back, Brighton Beach</p>
         </div>
         <img src="images/lookingback.jpg.JPG">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
         <div id="img-name">
          <p>Heart Shaped Flocks, Brighton Pier</p>
         </div>
         <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2GGn.jpg">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```